# webdriver-manager not using proxy in order to update

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver-manager

I'm developing a bot and using webdriver-manager (https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager) with the purpose to update the chromedriver file. The following error raise after the use of the install() method.
The following is the code to open the crhome driver. I use the chrome options to keep the browser open.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.path, chrome_options=chrome_options, service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

It generates the following error:

```
raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x03D14A30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]
```

I believe this is a proxy error, but I tried to configure a proxy in the environment and it did not worked.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Information regarding the code was added.

Comment: what is self.path

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are having is because you are giving path to the drivers + using chrome driver manager to install drivers. This use is wrong you must use one of them. And the keyword for argument option is wrong. Try this

```
 wd = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
```