# Webdriver Manager+Chrome Headless+Selenium+Python: webdriver does not respond to options

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

**System setup:**

- I used **Python 3.10** in my setup.
- I used **Selenium 4**.
- I used the Python **webdriver manager** in my test setup. (https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)
- I used **unittesting** for some test **pytest**.

**Details:**

Currently, my test setup and the included test cases work under Chrome as a normal GUI call, and the test cases run through under those conditions.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)


class OpenDevcrowd(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True
```

I have used the options from 2020/2021 to change my setup to headless.

I tried the following information from stackoverflow in my build, but had no success with it at all:

- [webdriver-manager not using proxy in order to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71755991/webdriver-manager-not-using-proxy-in-order-to-update)
- [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver)

**Issue:**

It seems that the options (and I tried almost all the options from the information already found in stackoverflow) would not work anymore?

Only the GUI is still called, and the headless option is simply not used.

**Questions:**

Did the command range change somehow from 2020/21 to 2022?

Is it the webdriver manager that prevents the options from being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

--headless should come with --window-size

Ex: "--window-size=1920,1080"

Comment: Oh man, I'm a little embarrassed about that now. Of course that was the solution!